# disable script in amp pages wordpress

Tags: wordpress

i have error in my amp pages
This code inserts plugin ajax-hits-counter:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><![CDATA[function ahc_getXmlHttp(){var e;try{e=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")}catch(t){try{e=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")}catch(n){e=false}}if(!e&&typeof XMLHttpRequest!="undefined"){e=new XMLHttpRequest}return e};var ahc_xmlhttp=ahc_getXmlHttp();ahc_xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://example.org/wp-content/plugins/ajax-hits-counte5r/increment-hits.rapid.php?post_id=547754&t="+(parseInt(new Date().getTime()))+"&r="+(parseInt(Math.random()*100000)));ahc_xmlhttp.send(null);]]></script>
```

AMP validator writes: **The tag 'script' is disallowed except in specific forms.**

Here insert the script function:

```
   public function appendScript( $content )
{
    global $post;

    if( is_single() || is_page() ) 
    {
        if( $this->getOption('use_rapid_incrementer')==1 )          // use rapid incrementer
        {
            $incrementer_url = plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'increment-hits.rapid.php?post_id='.$post->ID.'&t=';
        }
        else                                                // use simple incrementer
        {
            $incrementer_url = admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ).'?action='.$this->plugin_alias.'-increment&post_id='.$post->ID.'&t=';
        }

        $content .=
            '<script type="text/javascript">'.
                'function ahc_getXmlHttp(){var e;try{e=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")}catch(t){try{e=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")}catch(n){e=false}}if(!e&&typeof XMLHttpRequest!="undefined"){e=new XMLHttpRequest}return e};'.
                'var ahc_xmlhttp=ahc_getXmlHttp();'.
                'ahc_xmlhttp.open('.
                    '"GET", "'.$incrementer_url.'"+(parseInt(new Date().getTime()))+"&r="+(parseInt(Math.random()*100000))'.
                    ');'.
                'ahc_xmlhttp.send(null);'.
            '</script>';
    }

    return $content;
}
```

How to remove this script from the AMP page?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution.

1. You can insert the script using the wordpress plugin 'My Custom
   Functions' https://wordpress.org/plugins/my-custom-functions/.
2. Then go to the Plugin Manager setting of AMPforWP plugin (Assuming
   you have AMPforWP plugin of ampforwp.com installed ).
3. There you can disable My Custom Function plugin from executing on
   AMP pages.

AMPforWP's Plugin Manager page screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xq6Uz.jpg. It worked for me as I was trying to disable a script on AMP page which was being inserted by my custom function plugin.

Answer (score 1):

**If you are using Wordpress and have this issue,**

Google Search console was throwing an error for a few of my Wordpress Blog pages. Google was not able to index my AMP pages for my Blog. The error was that some custom JavaScript and CSS were injected into the AMP pages. Upon investigation, I found out that W3 Total cache was injecting minified JS (JavaScript) and CSS (Cascading Style Sheets) links into the pages.

**Errors showing up in search console:**

Custom JavaScript is not allowed

External stylesheets not supported, except for whitelisted font providers.

**Why this error comes up?**

Well, AMP pages should be lightweight so that it loads very fast on slow mobile devices. And as such there should be no javaScript or CSS in your AMP pages. Whenever Google bots find it, it throws an error.

**How to fix?**

For W3 Total Cache you need to activate the AMP extension. This will remove all the custom JS and CSS from the AMP pages. Go to your site Admin Dashboard - Performance - Extensions and activate AMP. W3 Total Cache comes built-in with the extension. You just need to activate it.

Here a step by step tutorial: https://josephkhan.me/custom-javascript-is-not-allowed-amp/

Here is a Youtube video that shows the steps to fix this issue: https://youtu.be/Luy1P1g7BEc